# When should I use AWS and when not

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, deployment, vps

I have a question which is in my mind since a long time now. I want to start a new project and will also try to attract business attention with it just to say that it is no private or internal company product in the end.

Before starting to develop I am also thinking about the environment on which I will run my application later on. In the past I always got a VPS server and just deployed my app + database + elasticsearch/redis/whatever there.

Recently I got more into AWS and pretty much like the idea of it. But on the other side it seems more expensive.

Let's say I deploy my app on a EC2 instance with a RDS instance as a database and S3 bucket for my static files.

That would be 3 or 4 times the money I would pay for a standard VPS server which is a lot starting out as a project where it is unsure if it will gain public attraction or not.

But also I know in case the app starts to grow it is much easier to handle it with AWS compared to a VPS.

Which do you guys choose in which situations? Is it advisible to start using a VPS and migrating to AWS later on?

Thanks for you answers.

Comment: It also depends on what application you are building and what approx you are paying for VPS

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare a regular VPS and AWS. A VPS is a shared hosting, and you don't know who others will be your neighbours (or how much resource will they consume). A VPS is a good start for project development and/or demonstration purposes - but you can also use AWS Free Tier services for the same reason.

The most important part is to get prepared for AWS (or any other cloud provider) during the development. Have your (micro)services to run individually and stateless, implement database sharding possibilities from the beginning, implement logging and correlation ID early, enable and apply service discovery within components - and the trends shows up to have them in docker containers which are getting the configuration from file(s) or ENV variable(s).

If I were you I just do the following: start the development on an existing VPS, if it reaches the [MVP/MVE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_viable_product) phase migrate it to AWS free tier components (maybe use 2-3 different account for keeping the costs at zero), and if the business goes up, migrate it to a paid account.

Comment: I can't seem to understand how is a VPS considered a shared hosting? :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on how much flexibility you would like to have.
When you are thinking a simple project, says installing web, application and database inside the same server, VPS would be a good choice due to its simplicity.
But when the time goes by, you might have a chance to upgrade your VPS due to performance issue which involves the help from VPS provider.
In my experience, it might be a difficult task based on the support level of your VPS provider but it might only need to perform a shutdown on EC2 interface for upgrading.

It would not be a fair competition when you compare EC2+S3+RDS to VPS because what you are comparing is renting 3 different servers with one server.
So the cost of using such AWS combination would definitely higher than a normal VPS.

The true beauty of AWS will be shown when you start to expand your infrastructure as there are load balancer service and you can even perform auto scaling if needed.

So my suggestion is that you can rent a VPS first, try to test how many clients you can reach.
Then base on the value and how much money you have gained, then consider AWS as your next step.

Answer (score 0):

What you are really asking is "how can I avoid a success disaster?"

Arrange your project so that if it is a success you can quickly and easily move it to AWS

Comment: In a way... But more or less I am also asking about experiences made by more experienced developers